# AEM servlet for a component that is not under /content?

Tags: aem

My goal is to create a token whenever a page is rendered that contains a component called someTeaser. This someTeaser component renders in the template after the content and before the footer and is not editable. It is configured fixed in the template structure.

The problem appears when I want to create a servlet for someTeaser. This component is not in the Content Repository crxde.

```
@SlingServletResourceTypes(
        resourceTypes = {Constants.ResourceTypes.SOME_TEASER},
        selectors = {"token"},
        extensions = Constants.Extensions.JSON
)
```

The resource for this component is `/conf/xx/settings/wcm/templates/someTemplate/structure/jcr:content/root/main/container/someTeaser`. This resource cannot be resolved in publish. It is not under content but rather under conf.

```
Request URL: https://publish_server/conf/xxx/settings/wcm/templates/someTemplate/structure/jcr:content/root/main/...

Request Method: GET

Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

An alternative solution would be to use define `resourceTypes = {Constants.ResourceTypes.PAGE}`  in the servlet but then every page will be checked for the selector token.

Can someone suggest an alternative solution for the task?

Comment: Is the token supposed to be part of the markup or is it requested with a separate HTTP request? If it's the former, why not make it a component with an HTL script?

Comment: The token is requested with a separate HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to request the token for the container that is avaliable in the JCR repository.

```
String containerPath =  PathBuilder.with(currentPage.getPath())
        .slash(AemConstants.JCR_CONTENT)
        .slash("root/main/container")
        .build();
```

and resolve the container url nicely using `resourceResolver.map(path)`.